# How to label a group ID based on linkage of the elements

Tags: sql

I have a data like:

```
# input
row id1 id2
-----------
1   a   b
2   a   c
3   d   e
4   f   g
5   g   h
6   h   k
```

and I want to make new group id based on "link" of IDs as follows:

```
# desired result
row id1 id2  new_group_id
-------------------------
1   a   b   1
2   a   c   1
3   d   e   2
4   f   g   3
5   g   h   3
6   h   k   3
```

where group 1 is labled because each rows of group 1 are connected by "a"(a-b, a-c), and group 3 is labeled because each rows are connected by "g" and "h"(f-g, g-h, h-k).

Any smart soltion for this? Thanks!

Comment: Please tag the question only with the DBMS you are really using because the solutions for each system might differ extremely.

Comment: why you are not using 'CASE WHEN' ?

Comment: @Abolfazl Who's using CASE WHEN

Comment: Could you add one more row to the input data `7   f   z`? How will it transfer to the desired result?

Comment: This is tricky :-(

Comment: @S-Man sorry, i've fixed the tags.

Comment: @SergeyGeron Thank you for the question.  Added `7  f  z` row will be categorized as group "3" because "f" appear in row 4 and 7.

Comment: What would happen with `7 d f`? You want a solution in Plain Standard SQL?

Comment: @S-Man thanks for good question! Adding `7 d f` is tricky. It will merge the current group 2 and 3 togather and will make a new larger group(group id 2).

Answer (score 1):

Just to observe, reformulated as...

```
SELECT MIN(row) x
     , MAX(row) y
     , id 
   FROM  
     ( SELECT row, id1 id FROM my_table
        UNION ALL
       SELECT row, id2 id FROM my_table
     ) a
  GROUP BY id;
```

...

it becomes a straightforward 'gaps-and-islands' problem, for which myriad solutions exist.

Comment: Thanks! But I still do not understand how the result of this query are connected to 'gaps-and-islands' problem. If you don't mind, could you please explain a bit more on how the result of this query are connected to 'gaps-and-islands' problem?